# PHP select query print out numerous items from database

Tags: php, sql, database

[My Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8ke5.png)

So I want it to print off like

```
Coffee Name:
ColumbianPrice: 7.99
Total Sold: 3
Total earnings: 23.9
```

And then to repeat for each type of coffee

Is there any web pages that allow me to do this

```
$a_result = mysqli_query($connection_var, "SELECT COF_NAME, PRICE FROM coffees");
while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($a_result)){
    print("<p>");
    print($rows[0]);
        print("<p>");

    print($rows[1]);
        print("<p>");

    print($rows[2]);
        print("<p>");

    print($rows[3]);
        print("<p>");

    print($rows[4]);
    print("</p>");
}
```

Currently, this is what I have but know it is not correct. Any help much appreciated?

Comment: Well you open 5 `p` elements but only close 1 so that's going to make for some strange formatting. You also are only selecting 2 columns but trying to access 5 indices so that's another issue. Please clarify `it is not correct`, values, display, other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to update the SQL query first, in order to retrieve data in the manner you want.

so let's say if your database table looks like below

```
Table: coffees

id    coffee_name    columbia_price   total_sold    total_earnings
-------------------------------------------------------------------
1     Raw Coffee     7.99             3             23.9
```

Your SQL query should be:

```
SELECT
`id` as `id`
`coffee_name` as 'Coffee Name:',
`coffee_price` as 'Columbia Price:',
`total_sold` as 'Total Sold:',
`total_earnings` as 'Total Earnings:',
from `coffees`;
```

And the expected output of this query should be

```
[
    [
        "id" => 1,
        "Coffee Name:" => 'Raw Coffee',
        "Columbia Price:" => '7.99',
        "Total Sold:" => '3',
        "Total Earnings:" => '23.9'
    ]
]
```

If you get the expected result, then PHP implement should be:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
        echo "<p>". $key ." ". $value ."</p>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should adjust your query to select all columns `SELECT * FROM coffees` and replace what's inside the while loop with something like this:

```
while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($a_result)){
    echo '<p>Coffee Name: ' . $rows[0] . '</p>';
    echo '<p>Coffee Price: ' . $rows[2] . '</p>';
    echo '<p>Total Sold: ' . $rows[3] . '</p>';
    echo '<p>Total Earnings: ' . $rows[4] . '</p>';
  }
```

This should be working fine with your table.

Answer (score 0):

```
$a_result = mysqli_query($connection_var, "SELECT COF_NAME, PRICE, SALES, TOTAL FROM coffees");

while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($a_result)){
    print("<p>");
    print("Coffee Name: $rows[0]<br>
        Price: $rows[1]<br>
        Total Sold: $rows[2]<br>
        Total Earnings: $rows[3]<br>");
}
    print("<p>");
```

Basically the answer